# Unable to reverse proxy on Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to change the base url when my nuxt3 app is deployed.

I am using the package [nuxt-proxy](https://github.com/wobsoriano/nuxt-proxy) on `"nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.11",`

I then add the following code to my nuxt.config.ts

```
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', '@pinia/nuxt', '@nuxtjs/i18n', 'nuxt-proxy'],
  proxy: {
    options: [
      {
        target: 'http://localhost:3003',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api/todos': '/todoz'
        },
        pathFilter: [
          '/api/todos',
        ],
      }],
  },
```

And then try to trigger this with

```
await useFetch<unknown>('http://localhost:3001/api/todos');
```

Checking my network tab to see if the the url appends `/todoz` at the end of the request url.

Nothing is happening, I cannot seem to trigger anything. I am completely fobbed.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: The given proxy module is not supported by Nuxt3: https://nuxt.com/modules?q=proxy&version=3.x Also, please use the stable beta rather than an RC version.

Comment: @kissu I wil revert to `3.0.0` . Can you please recommend a way forward for proxying? I must implement a runtime solution for our dev cloud instance. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I belive it is supported for `3.0.0`.

Comment: Not sure about that one since I don't use proxies, sorry.